# Inside stack after rotating positioned widget when moving the widget with gesture it moves to wrong direction

Tags: flutter, dart

**Can someone help me regarding this issue? When i try to rotate the widget and then try to move around, it moves into different direction**
*Here is dartpad link of the code*
https://dartpad.dev/49638ff48eca93d38e035a599721b2b0

First without rotating the widget, try to move the widget, by pressing on center where there is directional arrows showing, you will notice that it moves as desired,

But now try to rotate the widget 90 degrees or 180 degrees or any angle by pressing the bottom right corner where there is rotate icon, and then after rotating, try to move the widget, you will notice that its moving to different direction. I am not sure if its an issue of transform widget or i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix4 transformations are hard. Have a look at this package, it may help you:

https://pub.dev/packages/matrix4_transform

But also, if I were you, I'd put one widget inside of a second one. I would translate the external one, and then rotate the internal. This would prevent the translation coordinate system to rotate, which is what's happening to you.

Comment: I did try with matrix4_transform package, but still there is same issue. This is happening because i am using a stack as parent and positioned widget as child of it. In normal use cases, i don't face any issues with this package or normal matrix4 transformation.